# Hyperref: Scandinavian characters (æø) don't work in \url, hyperlink is wrong

Tags: hyperref, pdftex, unicode, urls, characters

#### Background

A while ago it became possible to use the letters æ, ø and å in URLs, and some websites, like the encyclopaedia Store Norske Leksikon, has made use of this.

Recently, a question was posted on a Norwegian forum about creating a hyperlink to such an URL, something that doesn't work, at least not with æ and ø.

#### An example

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\url{http://snl.no/øl} \\
\url{http://snl.no/ære} \\
\url{http://snl.no/Ål}
\end{document}
```

The first two links do not work, they are printed as `http://snl.no/\T1\ol` and `http://snl.no/\T1\aere`, but the third one works as it should.

(One can get the correct URL printed by using the `href` command, but as the hyperlink is still wrong, that isn't really a solution.)

#### The question

I assume this has something to do with how `hyperref` handles non-english characters. Is there some way of making `hyperref` create a correct link with æ or ø in the url?

#### Update

By using the `href` command, and compiling with `latex` and the `dvipdfm`, the hyperlink is correct (see gerry's answer below). I've been compiling with `pdflatex`.

Comment: Adding tags “url” and “unicode” could be helpful for people searching for this in future?

Comment: You're right, I added those, as well as `pdftex`. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I'd say this ought to work. Try asking on comp.text.tex.

Comment: Some other scattered suggestions: just `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` fix some characters: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/444468/250119 ■ see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/392970/250119 and `\hrefurl[urlencode]` in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/673889/250119 for an alternative solution to automatically convert URL to percent encoding ■ and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/562537/250119 for file paths. ■ also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/672441/250119 for line-breaking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually I can get the right link with `href`. It's compiled with `latex` & `dvi2pdf`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\href{http://snl.no/øl}{http://snl.no/øl}\\   \href{http://snl.no/ære}{http://snl.no/ære} \\   \href{http://snl.no/Ål}{http://snl.no/Ål}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed, it appears that this works. Thanks! I haven't compiled to DVI for a long time, so it didn't even occur to me to try.  I'll wait a little, and see if anyone has a solution for using pdflatex. If not, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 13):

With a small modification the answer given by gerry will even work directly with `pdflatex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
  \href{http://snl.no/%C3%B8l}{http://snl.no/øl} \\
  \href{http://snl.no/%C3%A6re}{http://snl.no/ære} \\
  \href{http://snl.no/%C3%85l}{http://snl.no/Ål}
\end{document}
```

You just have to encode the URL, for example using the [W3 URL Encoder](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp).

Answer (score 2):

I get the same results with pdflatex, latex+dvips+ps2pdf and latex+dvipdfmx. In your place I would ask the author of hyperref. E.g. in comp.text.tex.

Answer (score 1):

[matth's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34359/6865) works, but applying [Heiko's answer (to another question)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131332) it is even possible to do:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
  \href{\detokenize{http://snl.no/øl}}{http://snl.no/øl} \\
  \href{\detokenize{http://snl.no/ære}}{http://snl.no/ære} \\
  \href{\detokenize{http://snl.no/Ål}}{http://snl.no/Ål}
\end{document}
```

Saves the need to look up the code for `ø`, `æ`, and `Å`.