# National characters in URLs not working with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, urls, characters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hyperref: Scandinavian characters (æø) don't work in \url, hyperlink is wrong](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6906/hyperref-scandinavian-characters-aeo-dont-work-in-url-hyperlink-is-wrong)

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\url{http://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologi}

\url{http://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologisk_rum}

\url{http://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/Åben_mængde}

\url{http://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homøomorfi}

\url{http://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorffrum}

\end{document}
```

When not using `hyperref` the result comes out as expected. Adding `hyperref` gives me something similar to

```
http://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/Åben_m\T1\aengde
```

anyone have any idea how to fix this? There is nothing wrong with the URL.

Comment: *Slightly off-topic perhaps* there **is** something wrong with the url. According to the [RFC for URL](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) only `a-zA-Z0-9` and some special characters `$,-,_,.,+,!,*,',(,),","` where the `","` represents a `,`. Other characters can be encoded using `% hex hex` where `hex` follows `0-9[A-F|a-f]`. Apparently this RFC is no longer used?

Comment: As far as I know, the use of national chars in URLs have been allowed for some time.

Comment: This example works out of box in XeLaTeX.

Comment: Use `\href{http://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85ben_m%C3%A6ngde}{http://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/Åben_mængde}` instead. You have to encode the URL, for example using the [W3 URL encoder](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp).

Answer (score 4):

One of your links works (pdftex, miktex 2.9) with this:

```
\href{http://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/\string Åben_m\string ængde}{http://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/Åben\string_mængde}
```

But it is not very reliable. It fails (understandably) if I copy the code to an utf8 file. Also I don't know how much "intelligence" the pdf-reader has to invest to translate the link correctly in the whatever-it-is-called international notation. I think you should retry to get Heikos attention, probably he simply overlooked your question a c.t.t.