# Unicode symbols in hyperref links

Tags: hyperref, unicode, urls

EDIT:
It looks like this solution \detokenize{} is working in my situation. Mark it for answered.

I've searched all over Internet including Stackoverflow, but I can not found a solution in this problem:

```
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\href{run:/$HOME/Workspace/ĄČĘĖĮŠŲŪŽ/tests/V-832-2.qti}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Graph1}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Problem with this file is this (when I click onto a link in generated PDF):

```
Workspace/\begingroup \let \relax \relax \endgroup
[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ą}intopreamble]\begingroup \let \relax
\relax \endgroup
[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Č}intopreamble]\begingroup \let \relax
\relax \endgroup
[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ę}intopreamble]\begingroup \let \relax
\relax \endgroup
[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ė}intopreamble]\begingroup \let \relax
\relax \endgroup
[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Į}intopreamble]\begingroup \let \relax
\relax \endgroup
[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Š}intopreamble]\begingroup \let \relax
\relax \endgroup
[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ų}intopreamble]\begingroup \let \relax
\relax \endgroup
[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ū}intopreamble]\begingroup \let \relax
\relax \endgroup
[Pleaseinsert\PrerenderUnicode{Ž}intopreamble]/testams/V-832-2.qti
```

How to make [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) work with a Unicode paths?

Suggestions to use `utf8`, `utf8x` for [`inputenc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/inputenc) didn't work for me.

My inputenc is with those options: \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}.

Using a unicode=true tag didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Using `\usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}` doesn't help in your case?

Comment: Are you loading `inputenc`? With what option?

Comment: I get no error with utf8x. I would guess that your ucs version is outdated. You could try to do what the message says; Insert `\PrerenderUnicode{Ą}` and so on in your preamble. With utf8 as inputenc option one has first to add sensible definitions for the chars, e.g. with `newunicodechar`.

Comment: \unhbox \voidb@x \bgroup \let \unhbox \voidb@x \setbox \@tempboxa \hbox {u\global \mathchardef \accent@spacefactor \spacefactor }\accent 9 u\egroup \spacefactor \accent@spacefactor <---- I've got this string in a filename path only for one letter. It means that \PrerenderUnicode{} does not work in this situation.

Answer (score 9):

You can try:

```
\href{\detokenize{...}}{...}
```

Also I have doubts that `$HOME` can be used here, because a shell or similar is needed to interpret the environment variable.

Comment: Very useful. One question about this: how to make a href links absolute? Now href links file in relative path: $HOME/dir/file becomes &HOME/workdir/texfile:$HOME/dir/file.