# How to use Chinese characters in URLs?

Tags: pdftex, urls, cjk

If the URLs contain Chinese characters, the tex will output error.
I used PdfLaTeX. Here is my situation.

```
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{ref1}  \href{https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/中国-伊朗关系}{中国-伊朗关系}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{CJK}
```

Do anyone know how to solve this problem or how to convert Chinese characters in URLs into legal characters？

Comment: Welcome to tex.SX. Can you please post an MWE, i.e. a short, complete example that actually compiles?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/444458/250119 ■ https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131332/250119

Comment: @user202729 simply detokenizing will not give valid urls in the pdf (even if they often work). It is safer to use percent encoded url, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/606334/2388

Comment: Thank you, it really solved my problem. The browser usually change the Chinese characters to %, but it didn't change on wiki.