# How to append a Chinese-character string argument from an environment to first argument of \href

Tags: hyperref, luatex, urls, xparse

***P.S.:*** The answered OP "[Automatically convert unicode to percent encoding in href](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392970/automatically-convert-unicode-to-percent-encoding-in-href)" might be of interest.

A good answer must be able to be:

- compiled using **LuaLaTeX**

The MWE below creates a great URL for the first instance, namely `http://a.beautiful.url/?searchid=Test`, but it doesn't do so in the second instance, where it merely creates `http://a.beautiful.url/?searchid=`.

Now, this is because the URL is not being internationalized. But please note that the URL will depend on the (first and only) argument of the `mainentry` environment. In a good answer, the argument of this environment must be:

- input using **genuine Chinese characters**, not their percent-encoding as one would do when converting them for an internationalized URL

So, what matters to me is that they are at least input using genuine Chinese characters, e.g.

> 疊音詞

even though they might need to be converted to percent-encoding when using them in `http://a.beautiful.url/?searchid=` e.g. into

> %E7%96%8A%E9%9F%B3%E8%A9%9E

Lastly, a good answer will need to

- use a way of changing the inter-spacing between the Chinese characters throughout the document. In this case, we are using `\ltjsetparameter{kanjiskip=1em}` and `\ltjsetparameter{xkanjiskip=1em}` for that purpose. And thus we are **bound to the package `\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}`**.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xparse}

% Necessary for the fonts
\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\setmainjfont{HanWangKaiMediumChuIn_wp010-08}
\ltjsetparameter{kanjiskip=1em}
\ltjsetparameter{xkanjiskip=1em}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN
\IfEmptyTF
\tl_if_blank:nTF
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentEnvironment {mainentry} { m } {%
  \href{http://a.beautiful.url/?searchid=#1}{Click on me}%
}

\begin{document}

Tester

\begin{mainentry}{%
Test%
}
\end{mainentry}

疊音詞er

\begin{mainentry}{%
疊音詞%
}
\end{mainentry}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapted from the [answer by user David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/392979/67761) and the [comment by User guest](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392970/automatically-convert-unicode-to-percent-encoding-in-href#comment976504_392979) in the OP "[Automatically convert unicode to percent encoding in href](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392970/automatically-convert-unicode-to-percent-encoding-in-href)"

**Added code:**

```
\makeatletter
\directlua{function url_encode(str)
  if (str) then
    str = string.gsub (str, "\string\n", "\string\r\string\n")
    str = string.gsub (str, "([^\@percentchar w \@percentchar -\@percentchar _\@percentchar .\@percentchar \string~])",
        function (c) return string.format ("\@percentchar \@percentchar \@percentchar 02X", string.byte(c)) end)
    str = string.gsub (str, " ", "+")
  end
  return str    
end}
\makeatother
%
\def\percentifier#1{\directlua{
tex.print(url_encode('\detokenize{#1}'))
}}
```

**Modified code:**

```
  \href{http://a.beautiful.url/?searchid=#1}{Click on me}%
```

into

```
  \href{http://a.beautiful.url/?searchid=\percentifier{#1}}{Link}%
```

## MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xparse}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% MODIFIED CODE
\makeatletter
\directlua{function url_encode(str)
  if (str) then
    str = string.gsub (str, "\string\n", "\string\r\string\n")
    str = string.gsub (str, "([^\@percentchar w \@percentchar -\@percentchar _\@percentchar .\@percentchar \string~])",
        function (c) return string.format ("\@percentchar \@percentchar \@percentchar 02X", string.byte(c)) end)
    str = string.gsub (str, " ", "+")
  end
  return str    
end}
\makeatother
%
\def\percentifier#1{\directlua{
tex.print(url_encode('\detokenize{#1}'))
}}
% MODIFIED CODE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Necessary for the fonts

\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\setmainjfont{MingLiU}
\ltjsetparameter{kanjiskip=1em}
\ltjsetparameter{xkanjiskip=1em}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN
\IfEmptyTF
\tl_if_blank:nTF
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentEnvironment {mainentry} { m } {%
  \href{http://a.beautiful.url/?searchid=\percentifier{#1}}{Link}% MODIFIED CODE
}

\begin{document}

Tester

\begin{mainentry}{%
Test%
}
\end{mainentry}

疊音詞er

\begin{mainentry}{%
疊音詞%
}
\end{mainentry}

\end{document}
```