# hyperref fails with c-cedilla in a link

Tags: hyperref

The following forces an error

```
\href{https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouvernement_de_la_République_française}{France}
```

replacing or deleting the ç stops the error

Error reported:

> ! Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@tempa.

The preamble includes:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}
```

Anyone any suggestions or a workaround?

Comment: See also: [pdftex - Hyperref: Scandinavian characters (æø) don't work in \url, hyperlink is wrong - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6906/hyperref-scandinavian-characters-%C3%A6%C3%B8-dont-work-in-url-hyperlink-is-wrong)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to load the `fontenc` package with the option `T1`. (The default is still `OT1`.) In contrast it shouldn't be necessary to load the `inputenc` package with the option `utf8` *unless* your LaTeX format isn't fully up to date. (LaTeX formats since 2018-04-01 are OK.)

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % not unless LaTeX format isn't up to date
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  % <-- this one matters
\usepackage[spaces,obeyspaces,hyphens]{url} % optional
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\href{https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouvernement_de_la_République_française}{France}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping the url in \detokenise{} does the job

```
\href{\detokenize{https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouvernement_de_la_République_française}}{France}
```