# Accents in file path

Tags: unicode, href

I'm trying to link to a file in a folder named `Códigos`. My minimal code looks like this.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \begin{document}
        \href{run:./Códigos/test.c}{\texttt{test.c}}
    \end{document}
```

The PDF generates alright, but when I try opening the link, I realize that LaTeX has interpreted the accent as plain TeX code, and is as such unable to open the file.

I've tried using percent-encoding (writing `\%F3` instead of `ó`), but this doesn't seem to work for file paths. I've also tried to use the `verbatim` package, but every time I do so, it just throws me a `TeX capacity exceeded` error.

Finally, I've tried using `\detokenize` on the file path, but when I do so, regardless of whether I use characters like `ó` or not, Adobe Acrobat treats the link as if I was trying to connect to it, rather than opening it, and doesn't let me open the file.

Comment: Related question, [pdftex - Hyperref: Scandinavian characters (æø) don't work in \url, hyperlink is wrong - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6906/hyperref-scandinavian-characters-%C3%A6%C3%B8-dont-work-in-url-hyperlink-is-wrong)

Answer (score 1):

So, I figured out something... sort of. I can use `\detokenize` not on the whole file path, but only on the part after `run:`.

```
    \href{run:\detokenize{./Códigos/test.c}}{\texttt{test.c}}
```

If I do this, though, different PDF viewers get weirded out. The PDF viewer that comes with TeXWorks does interpret the file path correctly (as verified by doing a mouseover), but doesn't let me open it for whatever reason. Adobe Acrobat Reader does try to open the file, but interprets the `ó` as `Ã³`, because of [encoding mismatches](https://i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html). I've tried other viewers, but none seem to be able to actually open the file.

I guess the only solution here is to avoid the problem altogether, and remove the accent from the file path.

Comment: With o without LaTeX, avoid accents and spaces in directories and file names is always a good idea.