# Unicode chars in URL with XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, unicode, url

I want to print an URL with greek chars (compiling with XeLaTeX), but the below script fails to display the greek chars in the URL (they are displayed as underscores), while if I enclose the greek chars of URL in `\textgreek` I get an error.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{greek}

%\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek, Scale=MatchUppercase, Ligatures=TeX]{Gentium Plus}
\newfontfamily\greekfont{CMU Serif}

\usepackage{hyperref,xurl}

\begin{document}

δημοτικο-κεντρο-εικαστικων

\textgreek{δημοτικο-κεντρο-εικαστικων}

\url{http://www.elemesos.com/index.php/municipalities/2018-12-20-10-21-59/item/14463-δημοτικο-κεντρο-εικαστικων-τεχνων-αποθηκεσ-παπαδακη-3-9-2014.html}


\end{document}
```

Greek chars outside `\url` are displayed correctly, either inside or outside `\textgreek`.

Am I doing something wrong?

P.S. I use package `xurl` because it breaks the links at every character.

Comment: See also: [pdftex - Hyperref: Scandinavian characters (æø) don't work in \url, hyperlink is wrong - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6906/hyperref-scandinavian-characters-%C3%A6%C3%B8-dont-work-in-url-hyperlink-is-wrong?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that there's not really a fallback mechanism for the Unicode characters to be output in another font if the current font lacks them. lmtt, which is the default typewriter font in XeLaTeX, does not have the Greek characters. There is, however, CMU Typewriter Text which does have them. Adding the line `\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}`¹ to your document preamble will switch to that variation of Computer Modern and you'll get your Greek characters.

I'd also note that in your document, the first instance of δημοτικο-κεντρο-εικαστικων is set in Times New Roman (which has been extended to cover Greek in Unicode). Your second instance, enclosed in `\textgreek` uses the designated Greek font of CMU Serif, although I would be inclined to omit the `\newfontfamily\greekfont` to go for that font (although it appears that you may have done this to make the MWE manageable for those without Gentium Plus).

---

1. Or any monospace font that has Unicode coverage for Greek.

Comment: The link will be wrong. The url must internally be percent encoded.

Comment: Yes, I know that greek text looks different outside and inside `\textgreek`, it was done only for MWE purposes, and in real world I'm using Gentium Plus. Can you suggest more monospace font in addition to "CMU Typewriter Text" (which anyway looks a good option)? Does Gentium Plus have a monospace version?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Actually if I copy the link form the PDF, whether it displays greek chars or not (underscore replacements), when I paste it in a browser I get the original link percent encoded,

Comment: @mmj sure, but in the pdf it will wrong. It can work with some viewers, but it is not reliable.

Answer (score 6):

As Don wrote you need at first a font with greek chars. But beside this the url must also be percent encoded in the PDF to work correctly.

This means you should use `\href`:

```
\href{http://www.dezemeros.com/index.php/2018-12-20-10-21-59/14463-%CE%B4%CE%B7%CE%BC%CE%BF%CF%84%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%BF-%CE%BA%CE%B5%CE%BD%CF%84%CF%81%CE%BF-%CE%B5%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%B1%CF%83%CF%84%CE%B9%CE%BA%CF%89%CE%BD-%CF%84%CE%B5%CF%87%CE%BD%CF%89%CE%BD-%CE%B4%CE%B7%CE%BC%CE%BF%CF%84%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%BF-%CE%BA%CE%B5%CE%BD%CF%84%CF%81%CE%BF-%CE%B5%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%B1%CF%83%CF%84%CE%B9%CE%BA%CF%89%CE%BD-%CF%84%CE%B5%CF%87%CE%BD%CF%89%CE%BD.html}
{http://www.dezemeros.com/index.php/2018-12-20-10-21-59/14463-δημοτικο-κεντρο-εικαστικων-τεχνων-δημοτικο-κεντρο-εικαστικων-τεχνων.html}
```

As the second argument is simply text you can use there various formatting commands, e.g. \texttt or \textgreek or \nolinkurl.

With the new pdfmanagement of LaTeX, which is currently in the testphase you can let url do the percent encoding with the option `urlencode`:

```
\DocumentMetadata{pdfversion=2.0}

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}
\usepackage{hyperref,xurl}

\begin{document}

\url[urlencode]{http://www.dezemeros.com/index.php/2018-12-20-10-21-59/14463-δημοτικο-κεντρο-εικαστικων-τεχνων-δημοτικο-κεντρο-εικαστικων-τεχνων.html}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see, thanks. However, since my starting point is just the greek non-percent-encoded URL and I have hundreds of URL to handle, how can I obtain on-the-fly the percent-encoded first argument of `\href` starting from the second argument?

Comment: well the second part of my answer does get it on the fly ... (the pdfmanagement also has an `\hrefurl` command which can do the encoding too).

Comment: I fixed the link in the question and tested it again, and it seems working from the PDF regardless of using your second solution or not. It works even from my not-displaying MWE.

Comment: You mean without percent encoding? Well as I said: it depends on the pdf viewer. With some even wrong links work. But if you want to sent the pdf to someone else you shouldn't expect them to use your pdf viewer so better create correct links.

Comment: Ok, I believe you, my problem now is that it seems I can't install a valid "CMU Typewriter Text" font on my Windows 10 system, XeLaTeX keeps complaining with `dvipdfmx:fatal: Invalid font: -1 (1)`, both with TTF and OTF (converted online from TTF). I was able to install a working "FreeMono" font but I don't like it.

Comment: does it work with lualatex?

Comment: Yes, it works, but my real world document doesn't, I need to make it work with XeLaTeX.

Comment: well if the font works with lualatex but not with xelatex then xelatex finds perhaps the wrong font. Get the exact file name of the font (at the end of the log of the lualatex run) and then try \setmonofont{<file name>}

Comment: My bad, I forgot I have a `\urlstyle{sf}` that was switching urls to Sans Serif, so I added `\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}` and now it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127907/discussion-between-mmj-and-ulrike-fischer).